# PHP switch: encryption and decryption

Tags: php, switch-statement

I want to make my own encryption but this keeps happening

Input: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Output: `?b??efghi?????o?qrstuvwxy?`

Here is my code

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: Stan
* Date: 13-1-2017
* Time: 14:33
*/
function Encript($string)
{
    switch ($string) {
        case "a" : 
            $int = 1;
        break;
        case "b" :
            $int = 2;
        break;
        case "c" :
            $int = 3;
        break;
        case "d" :
            $int = 4;
        break;
        case "e" :
            $int = 5;
        break;
        case "f" :
            $int = 6;
        break;
        case "g" :
            $int = 7;
        break;
        case "h" :
            $int = 8;
        break;
        case "i" :
            $int = 9;
        break;
        case "j" :
            $int = 10;
        break;
        case "k" :
            $int = 11;
        break;
        case "l" :
            $int = 12;
        break;
        case "m" :
            $int = 13;
        break;
        case "n" :
            $int = 14;
        break;
        case "o" :
            $int = 15;
        break;
        case "p" :
            $int = 16;
        break;
        case "q" :
            $int = 17;
        break;
        case "r" :
            $int = 18;
        break;
        case "s" :
            $int = 19;
        break;
        case "t" :
            $int = 20;
        break;
        case "u" :
            $int = 21;
        break;
        case "v" :
            $int = 22;
        break;
        case "w" :
            $int = 23;
        break;
        case "x" :
            $int = 24;
        break;
        case "y" :
            $int = 25;
        break;
        case "z" :
            $int = 26;
        break;
        default :
            $int = 0;
        break;
    }
    return $int;
}
function Decript($int)
{
    switch ($int) {
        case 0 :
            $text = " ";
        break;
        case 1 :
            $text = "a";
        break;
        case 2 :
            $text = "b";
        break;
        case 3 :
            $text = "c";
        break;
        case 4 :
            $text = "d";
        break;
        case 5 :
            $text = "e";
        break;
        case 6 :
            $text = "f";
        break;
        case 7 :
            $text = "g";
        break;
        case 8 :
            $text = "h";
        break;
        case 9 :
            $text = "i";
        break;
        case 10 :
            $text = "j";
        break;
        case 11 :
            $text = "k";
        break;
        case 12 :
            $text = "l";
        break;
        case 13 :
            $text = "m";
        break;
        case 14 :
            $text = "n";
        break;
        case 15 :
            $text = "o";
        break;
        case 16 :
            $text = "p";
        break;
        case 17 :
            $text = "q";
        break;
        case 18 :
            $text = "r";
        break;
        case 19 :
            $text = "s";
        break;
        case 20 :
            $text = "t";
        break;
        case 21 :
            $text = "u";
        break;
        case 22 :
            $text = "v";
        break;
        case 23 :
            $text = "w";
        break;
        case 24 :
            $text = "x";
        break;
        case 25 :
            $text = "y";
        break;
        case 26 :
            $text = "z";
        break;
        default :
            $text = "?";
        break;
    }
    return $text;
}

$int = strtolower("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
echo "Original : ".$int;
$array = str_split($int);
$totalNumber = "";
$total = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $number = Encript($array[$i]);
    $number = $number + 0.22;
    $number = $number * 20.12;
    $totalNumber .= $number."/";
}
echo "<br>Encription = ".$totalNumber;
$backwards = explode("/",$totalNumber);
$countBackwards = count($backwards)-1;

$totalText = "";
for($j = 0; $j < $countBackwards; $j++)
{
    $int = $backwards[$j];
    $int = $int / 20.12;
    $int = $int - 0.22;
    var_dump($int);
    $text = Decript($int);
    $totalText .= $text;
}
echo "<br>";
echo "Decription : ".$totalText;
```

I know it's not the cleanest code, but i will clean it up when I found the problem.
The input is abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, and that also must be the outcome after the decript. 
But after the decode I get this : ?b??efghi?????o?qrstuvwxy?

Comment: Can you update your question to state what you want as a result, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: I've changed @Darren

Comment: This is not encryption, you are doing encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to round the output of substraction it will solve your problem:

```
$totalText = "";
for($j = 0; $j < $countBackwards; $j++)
{
    $int = $backwards[$j];
    $int = $int / 20.12;

    $int = round($int - 0.22); // Rounded the final output

    //var_dump($int);
    $text = Decript($int);
    $totalText .= $text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this its work just replace Decript(strval($int));  ...

```
function Encript($string)
{
switch ($string) {
    case "a" :
        $int = 1;
        break;
    case "b" :
        $int = 2;
        break;
    case "c" :
        $int = 3;
        break;
    case "d" :
        $int = 4;
        break;
    case "e" :
        $int = 5;
        break;
    case "f" :
        $int = 6;
        break;
    case "g" :
        $int = 7;
        break;
    case "h" :
        $int = 8;
        break;
    case "i" :
        $int = 9;
        break;
    case "j" :
        $int = 10;
        break;
    case "k" :
        $int = 11;
        break;
    case "l" :
        $int = 12;
        break;
    case "m" :
        $int = 13;
        break;
    case "n" :
        $int = 14;
        break;
    case "o" :
        $int = 15;
        break;
    case "p" :
        $int = 16;
        break;
    case "q" :
        $int = 17;
        break;
    case "r" :
        $int = 18;
        break;
    case "s" :
        $int = 19;
        break;
    case "t" :
        $int = 20;
        break;
    case "u" :
        $int = 21;
        break;
    case "v" :
        $int = 22;
        break;
    case "w" :
        $int = 23;
        break;
    case "x" :
        $int = 24;
        break;
    case "y" :
        $int = 25;
        break;
    case "z" :
        $int = 26;
        break;
    default :
        $int = 0;
        break;
}
return $int;
}

function Decript($int)
{
switch ($int) {
    case "0" :
        $text = " ";
        break;
    case 1:
        $text = "a";
        break;
    case 2 :
        $text = "b";
        break;
    case 3 :
        $text = "c";
        break;
    case 4 :
        $text = "d";
        break;
    case 5 :
        $text = "e";
        break;
    case 6 :
        $text = "f";
        break;
    case 7 :
        $text = "g";
        break;
    case 8 :
        $text = "h";
        break;
    case 9 :
        $text = "i";
        break;
    case 10 :
        $text = "j";
        break;
    case 11 :
        $text = "k";
        break;
    case 12 :
        $text = "l";
        break;
    case 13 :
        $text = "m";
        break;
    case 14 :
        $text = "n";
        break;
    case 15 :
        $text = "o";
        break;
    case 16 :
        $text = "p";
        break;
    case 17 :
        $text = "q";
        break;
    case 18 :
        $text = "r";
        break;
    case 19 :
        $text = "s";
        break;
    case 20 :
        $text = "t";
        break;
    case 21 :
        $text = "u";
        break;
    case 22 :
        $text = "v";
        break;
    case 23 :
        $text = "w";
        break;
    case 24 :
        $text = "x";
        break;
    case 25 :
        $text = "y";
        break;
    case 26 :
        $text = "z";
        break;
    default :
        $text = "?";
        break;
}
return $text;
}
$int = strtolower("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
echo "Original : ".$int;
$array = str_split($int);
$totalNumber = "";
$total = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $number = Encript($array[$i]);
    $number = $number + 0.22;
    $number = $number * 20.12;
    $totalNumber .= $number."/";
}
echo "<br>Encription = ".$totalNumber;
$backwards = explode("/",$totalNumber);
$countBackwards = count($backwards)-1;

$totalText = "";
for($j = 0; $j < $countBackwards; $j++)
{
    $int = $backwards[$j];
    $int = $int / 20.12;
    $int = $int - 0.22;

    var_dump($int);

    $text = Decript(strval($int));
    $totalText .= $text;
}
echo "<br>";
echo "Decription : ".$totalText;
```

Thank you ....

Comment: my code is also run correctly in your way please try it